# Defining the length of a vector within a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct, std

The struct I want to use is defined below. (I am using `namespace std`):

```
struct body {string name; float m; vector< float > p; vector< float > v;};
```

This compiles, but later I get a segmentation fault at run time. I know this is because the vectors don't have a defined size (I want three components).

I have tried using the a vector constructor `vector x(3,0)`, but this won't compile. I get:

```
glib.h(5): error: expected a type specifier
  struct body {string name; float m; vector<float> p (3,0); vector<float> v(3,0);};
                                                      ^

glib.h(5): error: expected a type specifier
  struct body {string name; float m; vector<float> p (3,0); vector<float> v(3,0);};
                                                        ^

glib.h(5): error: expected a type specifier
  struct body {string name; float m; vector<float> p (3,0); vector<float> v(3,0);};
                                                                            ^

glib.h(5): error: expected a type specifier
  struct body {string name; float m; vector<float> p (3,0); vector<float> v(3,0);};
```

Basically, I need to allocate space for a vector of 3 elements when I define the struct, and I do not know how to do this. I am a C++ beginner and have done a lot of research, but I cannot find an answer. Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: If you always want 3 elements, then perhaps a `vector` is not the data structure you want.

Comment: I do always want three elements, but to do vector calculations wouldn't it be easy to use a vector?

Comment: "vector calculations"? not sure what you mean by that. `vector` is an array like structure for storing data, not the mathematical kind (normal, multiplication, etc.).

Comment: Ahh, I was confused with vector from a different library. I'll just write my own class for this then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options:

1) add a constructor to initialize the vectors to size 3:

```
struct body 
{
  body() : p(3), v(3) {}
  string name; 
  float m; 
  vector< float > p; 
  vector< float > v;
};
```

2) initialize the variables at the point of declaration (C++11)

```
struct body 
{
  string name; 
  float m; 
  vector< float > p = vector<float>(3); 
  vector< float > v = vector<float>(3);
};
```

3) Use `std::array<float, 3>` instead of vectors

```
struct body 
{
  body() : p(3), v(3) {}
  string name; 
  float m; 
  std::array<float, 3> p; 
  std::array<float, 3> v;
};
```

3) Use brace initialization to instantiate the struct.

```
body b1 {"hello", 3.14, vector(3,0), vector(3,0) };
```

Answer (score 1):

You call the vector constructor inside your constructor.

```
struct body {
    string name; 
    float m; 
    vector< float > p; 
    vector< float > v;

    body(): p(3,0), v(3,0) {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the size for the vector in the constructor for your `body`:

```
struct body {
    string name; 
    float m; 
    vector< float > p; 
    vector< float > v;

     body() : p(3), v(3) {}
};
```

C++11 allows you to specify constructor arguments "in place", so something like:

```
struct body {
    string name; 
    float m; 
    vector< float > p{3}; 
    vector< float > v{3};
};
```

...is allowed, but it sounds like your compiler doesn't support that (maybe time for an update?)

Edit: doing a bit of checking, it appears that not all compilers select the correct constructor when given the second piece of code. For example, given the code above, VC++ gives a vector containing 3 0's, but g++ gives a vector containing a single value of 3. In other words, g++ is using the overload that takes an initializer list, but VC++ is using the overload that takes one parameter.

For whatever it's worth, it appears that g++ is doing this correctly, and VC++ is incorrect<sup>1</sup>, but from a practical viewpoint it's of little consequence: code that uses it isn't portable, so most people probably want to avoid it (at least until the compiler vendors get their acts together).

---

1. The specific wording is at $13.3.1.7:

   - Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors (8.5.4) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
   - If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

`std::vector` has an intializer-list constructor, leaving on the question of whether it's viable. That comes down to the question of whether converting `3` to a `float` is a "narrowing conversion". In this case, the answer is no, it's not. The official wording is (§8.5.4/7):

> A narrowing conversion is an implicit conversion
>
> [ ... ]
>
> from an integer type or unscoped enumeration type to a floating-point type, except where the source is a constant expression and the actual value after conversion will fit into the target type and will produce the original value when converted back to the original type,

So, since we're using a constant expression with the value `3`, and `float` is guaranteed to be able to hold that value, and produce `3` as the result if we convert it back to `int`, it's *not* a narrowing conversion. That means the initializer-list constructor is viable, so it's the one that should be chosen.

In theory, if you want to do the in-place initialization, you should probably use:

```
std::vector<float> p{0, 0, 0};
```

...MS VC++, however, rejects this, reinforcing the previous advice that if you care about portability, you probably want to avoid this in general.

Comment: Or just add the appropriate flags to the compiler. Remember C++11 is not the default yet.

Comment: I don' think `()` are allowed in the second example, and `{}` could lead to the wrong constructor being called.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will create size one vectors with an element of value `3.0f`.

Comment: Interesting. I was pretty sure that, for a class that has a constructor with an initializer_list, that one trumps all the others if it is viable. The only thing I am not 100% sure about is whether the int to float conversion affects this.

Comment: @juanchopanza: See edited answer. Doing more reading, while the int-float conversion would *normally* be considered a narrowing conversion (which was why I thought the initializer-list shouldn't be viable in the first place), there's a loophole that allows it in this case.

Comment: I saw your edit, nice work! "uniform" initialization can be a bit of a minefield sometimes.